# Javascript table filter doesn't show table headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a script to filter a table based on a select value. The script works, the only problem is that it filter also the headers of the table, which Id like to show always.
This is the javascript and the table:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#mac').change(function() {

    var selection = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('table').find('tr');

    dataset.show();

    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
      return $(item).find('td:last-child').text().split(';').indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mac">
<table id="table_id" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
      <th>Scadenza</th>
      <th>Società</th>
      <th>Macrotema</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style=" background-color:">

      <td>Prescrizione</td>
      <td>Corsi di aggiornamento </td>
      <td>
        <nobr>2025/01/01</nobr>
      </td>
      <td>XXXX</td>
      <td>SEDE; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" background-color:">

      <td>Prescrizione</td>
      <td>Rinnovo iscrizione</td>
      <td>
        <nobr>2024/12/31</nobr>
      </td>
      <td>XXXX</td>
      <td>SEDE; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" background-color:">
  </tbody>

</table>
```

My question is: How can I edit the script to show the headers?

Thank you for your time :D
let me know if I have to explain the situation better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a more specific selector :

`var dataset = $('table tbody tr');`

Comment: Only this won't work if we clear the mac input. It will not return you any result.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below solution with output.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#mac').change(function() {

    var selection = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('table').find('tr');

    dataset.show();

    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
      return index !== 0 && $(item).find('td:last-child').text().split(';').map(x => x.trim()).indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mac">
<table id="table_id" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
      <th>Scadenza</th>
      <th>Società</th>
      <th>Macrotema</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style=" background-color:">

      <td>Prescrizione</td>
      <td>Corsi di aggiornamento </td>
      <td>
        <nobr>2025/01/01</nobr>
      </td>
      <td>XXXX</td>
      <td>SEDE; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" background-color:">

      <td>Prescrizione</td>
      <td>Rinnovo iscrizione</td>
      <td>
        <nobr>2024/12/31</nobr>
      </td>
      <td>XXXX</td>
      <td>SEDA; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" background-color:">
  </tbody>

</table>
```